# Cancel button the form doesnt work properly

Tags: python, django, forms, button, view

This is my form. Submit works properly fine. BUt with this I can only CANCEL, only when I fill all the fields. What I want is to cancel anytime and reach the main airlines page. Also, I want the cancel button in the form page.What will the be the solution??

```
<form action="{% url 'addairlines' %}" method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{form|crispy}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formaction="{% url 'addairlines' %}">Submit</button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" formaction="{% url 'airlines' %}">Cancel</button>

</form>
```

This is my main airlines view.

```
def airlines(request):
    content = {

        'Airlinesdata' : Airlines.objects.all()

    }
    return render(request, 'airlines/index.html', content)
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using an `<a>` tag instead of a `<button>`. You could give it the same classes.

Comment: Show views for `{% url 'airlines' %}`

Comment: But will it solve my problem??...Nadir Abbas

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to make the user go back to the index page by clicking a button:

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href = '/index.html';"> 
      Cancel
</button>
```

This code takes the user to the `index.html` file in the root directory.
You can change the `/index.html` to the page you want the user to go.